# Convert .cmd file into Windows Service - 1053 Error

Tags: windows, service, windows-command-prompt

I have a file "init.cmd" which has the following commands inside it:

```
set APP_ROOT=c:/wamp/www/myproj
ringo -b %APP_ROOT%/bin/init.js %APP_ROOT%/app/main.js
```

The file works fine when run from the command line, but I'd like to turn it into a Windows Service.

So I type:

sc create MyServiceName binPath= c:/wamp/www/myproj/bin/init.cmd

The service is created, but everytime I try to start it, it crashes saying:

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I have a similar problem w/ Mongo, which is much simpler.

From a command prompt typing:

```
c:/mongodb/bin/mongod
```

successfully starts the mongo server.

But trying to install a service as :

```
sc create mongo binPath= c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe
```

crashes on start everytime with the same error as above.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a services, or do you just need it to start when the computer starts?  You may be better off setting up a schedule task that is ran when the computer starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a service pointing at a batch file.  Create the service pointing to the ringo app, then edit the registry and give it the needed parameters.  Set a system wide variable to the value that you need.  That should allow the service to start.

Comment: I have the same problem with Mongo which isn't a batch file.

Comment: It may just be poor error reporting for different reasons.

Comment: Let's forget Mongo for the moment.  Am I able to have the service spawn a batch file AFTER it's been started?  The trouble is that I have to set a variable in the LOCAL scope of the app so a system wide variable will conflict with other apps - hence the batch file.

Comment: No, the service won't be able to run a batch file.  What you could do is throw together a small .NET app and have it set the local variable then launch the app.  Can you run the app under a local user account?  How about setting up an account and setting up a user variable with the correct setting.  That way it won't impact other apps on the system unless they are run under that specific local account.